# JS function working on chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

i'm experiencing a strange issue.

I have this jquery function

```
$('#availability-check-add-to-cart-form').submit(function() {
    debugger;
    var submitButton = $("#add-to-cart-button-form");
    try {
        var code = $('#availability-check-item-code').text().replace('#','');
        $('#availability-check-product-code').val(code);

        submitButton.attr('disabled', 'disabled');      
        hilti.addToCartAnimation(submitButton);
        $.post("/item/add.json", $(this).serialize())
        .success( function (data) {
            submitButton.removeAttr('disabled');
            hilti.updateCartCount(data.productAmount);
            var posName = $('#map-overlay h1').text();
            if(posName) {                   
                var nearestHiltiCenters = [];
                $("#checkAvailability-inner ul#mapsearch-results-list li strong").each(function() { nearestHiltiCenters.push($(this).text()) });
                $.post('/cart/updatePreferred', {'pointOfServiceName' : posName, 'nearestHiltiCenters[]' : nearestHiltiCenters});
            }                   
        }).error(function(data, serializedData, message) {
            submitButton.removeAttr('disabled');
            hilti.ajaxError(arguments);
        });

    }
    catch (e) {
        submitButton.removeAttr('disabled');
        hilti.ajaxError(e);
    }
    return false;
});
```

but, while it's properly working on chrome, it doesn't work on firefox as the post returns always an error. If we debug the code, the execution proceed properly, while in normal mode the post always return error.

I don't understand where is the problem... Any suggestion?

thanks in advance

Andrea

Comment: Why you use `POST` to fetch JSON file ? Try using `GET`.

Comment: i'm using post because i'm submitting form fields and i don't want to show parameters passed.....

@Han ... the error is that the post is not called

Comment: Does your code reach `hilti.addToCartAnimation(submitButton);` in FF?

Comment: yes it reached it...we put a consol log to print the $(this).serialize() and the data to be passed are correct

Comment: OK solved adding preventDefault